# Does sql_id change if bind variable values are changed

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have a sql_id. The corresponding SELECT SQL query has 4 bind variables.
There is a program created by me which lets me know that it ran for 1000 times in the last 1 month.
So basically I want to know that all 1000 times the same bind variable was used or not.
For the latest one, I got the bind variable values from v$sql_bind_capture.

So is it that whatever is the latest value in v$sql_bind_capture is the same used all 1000 times?
Does sql_id generation consider the bind value for generation of sql_id or it is the query without the bind value that is used to generate sql_id?

Thanks
Tarun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, different bind value passed each time will not cause the SQL_ID to change. A different bind value passed may cause the sql plan hash value to change (PHV) but not the SQL_ID.

Answer (score 1):

About your main question:

> so basically I want to know that all 1000 times the same bind variable was used or not.
> There are 2 standard ways to do that:

1. add hint "monitor" into the query and check bind variables values in v$sql_monitor. I have own script for that: https://github.com/xtender/xt_scripts/blob/master/rtsm/binds.sql
2. enable tracing for your sql_id:

   alter system set events 'sql_trace [sql:&sqlid] bind=true, wait=false';

&sqlid is substituion variable which you can set to to your needed sql_id. Then you can periodically check bind variables tracefiles, for example using grep.